# Why is it called a primitive root?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, intuition

I am looking for a paper or reference that explains why primitive roots are called primitive roots.  I know what they are but was wondering if there was a reason?

Comment: Usually the term primitive is a reference to a basic element where you can construct all the other terms from it.

Comment: Okay, so this basically just reiterates the idea of a generator.  Awesome.  Thanks

Comment: Yep that's right. The term is a lot older than abstract algebra, so there are some holdover names that have perfect analogues.